# Find $f(x)$, given $f(x+y) - 2f(x-y) + f(x) - 2f(y) = y - 2$

Tags: derivatives, functional-equations

For a differentiable function $f(x)$, $$f(x+y) - 2f(x-y) + f(x) - 2f(y) = y - 2.$$ Then find $f(x)$.

I am not able to think of any method which is working. I tried replacing $x$ and $y$, putting $x$ or $y = 0$, putting $y = x$, etc.
Can someone help me

Answer given at back is $f(x)=x+1$

Comment: By putting $y=0$ , you get $f(0)=1$, by putting $x=y$, and using the previous result you'll get $f(2x)-f(x)=x$ . Which may suggest that $f$ is linear. I don't know we can guarantee that or not but it is a guess. So $f(x)=ax+b$. Now using previous results $f=x+1$.

Comment: @PNDas you are right. Also, the function is differentiable so we can easily get to $f'(x+y) = f'(x-y) = f'(x)$. So it is indeed linear.

Comment: Can't figure out how to get $a = 1$...$f(1)=a+1$, did you have to find $f(1)$?

Comment: @DerekLuna, use $f(2x)-f(x)=x$.

Comment: Dear @NikhilRastogi, I was wondering why you haven't accepted any of the answers, as there are three fairly good answers there. In particular, I wonder whether you found my answer helpful or not. If you think it's not that good of an answer, I don't expect you to upvote, but that is something independent from accepting one of the answers. I would be glad to edit my answer to make it more useful, so feel free to tell me the parts that are not suitable as you see it. (I'll delete my comment after seeing your response).

Answer (score 1):

Another trick for solving. As PNDas has already mentioned $f(0) = 1$. Now substitute $y = h$ and do some grouping:

$$(f(x+h) - f(x)) - 2(f(x +(-h)) - f(x)) = h + 2(f(0 + h) - f(0))$$

Divide by $h$

$$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}h +2\frac{f(x +(-h)) - f(x)}{-h} = 1 +2\frac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}h$$
And take the limit as $h \to 0$ to get
$$3f'(x) = 1 + 2f'(0)$$
which by the assumption of differentiability is guaranteed to converge. Set $x = 0$ to find $f'(0)$, then it is a simple integration to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that the only function $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ satisfying
$$ f ( x + y ) - 2 f ( x - y ) + f ( x ) - 2 f ( y ) = y - 2 \tag 0 \label 0 $$
for all $ x , y \in \mathbb R $ is $ f ( x ) = x + 1 $, even without assuming that $ f $ is differentiable. It's easy to check that the mentioned function is a solution. To prove the converse, first define $ g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ with $ g ( x ) = f ( x ) - x - 1 $. Then \eqref{0} can easily be rephrased in terms of $ g $ to get
$$ g ( x + y ) - 2 g ( x - y ) + g ( x ) - 2 g ( y ) = 0 \text . \tag 1 \label 1 $$
Letting $ x = y = 0 $ in \eqref{1} we get $ g ( 0 ) = 0 $. Now, letting $ x = 0 $ in \eqref{1} we get
$$ - 2 g ( - y ) = g ( y ) \text . \tag 2 \label 2 $$
Substituting $ - y $ for $ y $ in \eqref{2} we get $ g ( - y ) = - 2 g ( y ) $, which together with \eqref{2} itself shows that $ g ( y ) = 0 $, and thus $ f ( y ) = y + 1 $ for all $ y \in \mathbb R $.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on the one provided by user **FhoToN** in this [AoPS post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h431915p2441592). (no differentiability needed nor used)

Let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion that $$f(x+y)-2f(x-y)+f(x)-2f(y)=y-2.$$

From $P(x,0)$ we get $-2f(0)=-2$, and so $$f(0)=1.$$

From $P(0,y)$ and previous we get
$$f(y)+2f(-y)=3-y.\tag{1}$$

From $P(0,-y)$ and previous we get
$$f(-y)+2f(y)=3+y.\tag{2}$$

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ as a system of equations (with variables $f(y)$ and $f(-y)$), we get $f(y)=y+1$ (notice that $y$ was arbitrary chosen and so this holds for all $y$). We can verify this is a solution, and thus the only one.